# SSRS display label at base of column chart columns

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am trying to get the labels of this column chat to appear at the columns base much like in the second image below. However that solution doesn't completely work as it skews the rest of the information.

Does anybody know the appropriate way to accomplish this, it's madding that this isn't straight forward.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm using the following data:

[image]

Take a standard Chart:

[image]

The first Chart Series is our data series, with a Chart Type of standard Column, and the second Chart Series based has a Chart Type of Line, based on a target value to get the required line in the Chart Area.

As you've probably seen, you do have some control over label placement, but not to meet your requirements. The best we can do is use the **Bottom** position for the label position, which isn't even close:

[image]

[image]

What can we do? First, remove the labels from the existing Series.

Next, add a new Series to the Chart:

[image]

Basically we're using a constant here, which should be the lower bound of the Y axis. I'm using *0* in this case.

This new Chart Series needs to be *first* in the order of all the Chart Series.

Change the Chart Type for the first two Chart Series to **Stacked Column**:

[image]

Add Series labels to this *new* Chart Series. Set the Label data expression under the **Series Label Properties**. The expression I've used is:

=Sum(Fields!val.Value, "CategoryGroup")

Since the two Chart Series share the same Scope, we can leverage this to get the values of the data group as above.

Here, `CategoryGroup` is the name of the **Category Group**:

[image]

The updated chart looks like:

[image]

And the result is labels at the *base* of each column as required:

[image]

Seems like the required result, even if it took a while to get there.

So, by using a dummy Chart Series which is at the base of the Y axis for each group, we can anchor the label at the bottom as required, and by using the label expression to display a *different* Chart Series value, it looks a label on the actual data group!

**Edit after comment**

You can definitely use expressions to set the minimum axis value and also the dummy Chart Series, it's just a case of whether you can get the exact one required.

In my example, say we change the axis value to the minimum in the Dataset:

[image]

i.e. `=Min(Fields!val.Value)`

Since the Dummy Chart Series would be looking at the Scope of each individual Category Group, we need a slightly different expression to get the same value:

```
=Min(Fields!val.Value, "DataSet1")
```

This changes the chart as we would expect:

[image]

You could also add a buffer to the value, something like:

```
=Min(Fields!val.Value) - 1
```

So you don't get columns with no height.

For more complex expressions, there may be issues, i.e. in 2008 you cannot get aggregates on aggregates, which might be useful, and even then it's difficult to bring this into the dummy Chart Series.

Sometimes, if possible, it's easiest to add columns to your Dataset with these values pre-generated and use these fields instead of trying to calculate it in the report.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for your detailed response. If I may however ask for one extra hint/tip. The chart that I am working on has auto start min and max values. After applying your solution I still end up with something close to my second image where the label position is correct but the columns and average bars (the blue and orange horizontal bars) are all wonky and the Y axis just has 00:00 instead  of the mm:ss that is implimented. 

Is there a way for me to grab the charts min value somehow dynamically?

Comment: You're welcome, unfortunately it's difficult to explain with words, hence all the screenshots. As above, you can definitely use expressions to get those min values, but it's tough to say if you can get the exact one required. One thing that's missing from the question is your specific data - if you still need help, maybe create a query to generate a Dataset using http://sqlfiddle.com/ so we are looking at the same data - just a few rows to show how things look for you.

Comment: I accepted you'r answer so I don't forget. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbc60/1 here is the sqlfiddle link to what I made. Its over simplistic but they are the two main pieces of data used in the chats, where the vehicle are along the x axis and the minute and seconds are along the y axis. The problem I am having is that what ever I try to set our dummy column to it causes something like my second image where the y axis has jut  00:00 and all of the columns line up. The y axis min and max values are set to auto so its not static.

Comment: Cool, I'll check this out. Based on those two columns, how is the column label worked out?

Comment: Wow, can't believe I skipped that! Sorry its trips, So the time column would should be more accurately called avgTime, where as you can guess is the average time the vehicle has made on each of its trips. And the Horizontal bars are averages over different time periods for all the vehicles, one being a day the other a week or so.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if you want the label to be vertical (90°rotation) and the numbers are bigger than 99. It gives a centred label on the x axis and the label overlap with the categories displayed there. (sad)

Comment: To answer my previous comment, it does work if you use "line" serie instead of "stacked column" for the fake invisible series. I found this trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29552401/4625305).

Comment: This answer is criminally underrated